# Using given properties as strings

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, sql-order-by

I would like to use a single, general method to retrieve an ordered list for a given string representing a property inside a lambda expression.

I know people requested this before but it didn't work for me. I tried this and it threw error:

```
db.Books.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Discount").GetValue(x,null))
        .Take(3);
```

I'm using this at the moment:

```
public IQueryable<Book> GetCheapestBooks()
{
    return db.Books.OrderBy(x => x.Discount)
                   .Take(3);
}
```

Comment: What was the error that was thrown by the first example? What does `results` equal in your second example?

Comment: i got this error: Cannot order by type 'System.Object'

Comment: I tried the suggestions, none worked except the .tolist() idea      (by L.B), but it has its flaws as stated so i'm not sure if i should use it over creating few more specific methods.

Comment: p.s: i mean the short suggestions by the way

Comment: ok guess it was syntax issue, here's working one:  results = (from book in db.Books orderby ("Discount") select book).Take(3);

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you are looking for:

[Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

With this you can write queries like:

```
var result = db.Books.OrderBy( "Discount" ).Take( 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple console application.

```
class A
        {
            public int prop1 { get; set; }
            public int prop2 { get; set; }
        }

    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<T> GenericOrderByDescending<T>(IEnumerable<T> arg, string property, int take)
        {
            return arg.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(x, null)).Take(take);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            IEnumerable<A> arr = new List<A>()
                                     {
                                         new A(){ prop1 = 1, prop2 = 2},
                                         new A(){prop1 = 2,prop2 =2},
                                         new A(){prop1 = 3,prop2 =2},
                                         new A(){prop1 = 441,prop2 =2},
                                         new A(){prop1 = 2,prop2 =2}
                                     };

            foreach(var a1 in GenericOrderByDescending<A>(arr, "prop1", 3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a1.prop1);
            }
        }
    }
```

U can pass your `db.Boks.AsEnumerable()` as parameter for `GenericOrderByDescending<T>()` method. Instead of T you should type the type of your `db.Boks` items. My example sorts an array of instances of class `A` and I've got  no errors, it works fine. Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
public IQueryable<Book> GetCheapestBooks()
{
    db.Books.OrderBy(x => x.Discount).Take(3).AsQueryable<Book>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method which creates the property expression:

```
private static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
    MemberExpression propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, prop);

    Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), prop.PropertyType);
    Type keySelectorType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(funcType);
    LambdaExpression keySelector = Expression.Lambda(funcType, propExpr, paramExpr);

    MethodInfo orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), prop.PropertyType);
    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>) orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, keySelector });
}
```